# raspberry pi video streaming through SPI

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, spi

I'm somewhat beginner in gstreamer.

I am trying to stream live video from raspberry pi to MSP430 MCU over SPI connection.

What I am thinking right now is get the buffers directly from raspberry pi using appsink, and then send them through SPI connection.

But I am not sure where the buffers can be saved, and how they are saved.

I'm looking for examples using appsink, but not really sure whether I can continuously get a stream of buffers.

Is there any way that I can do that?

Or any other better way to stream a video over SPI connection can be helpful.

Thank you.